# Query monitoring changes in the field

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to program a query where I can see the changes that certain fields have undergone in a certain date period.
Example: From the **CAM_CONCEN** table bring those records where the **ACCOUNT_NUMBER** undergoes a modification in the **CONCTACT** field in a period of 6 months before the date.
I would be grateful if you can guide me.

Comment: How are you tracking changes to the column?  Are you using built-in auditing?  A trigger writing to a history table?  A trigger writing to a generic audit table?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` to peek at the previous row of a particular subset of rows (the same account in this case).

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select c.*,
    lag(contact) over(partition by account_number
                      order by change_date) as prev_contact
  from cam_concen c
) x
where contact <> prev_contact
```

Comment: thank you, it was successful.